# CONCAT(meta_key,meta_value) into different columns from wp_postmeta table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, if-statement, concatenation

After i made some researches about the problem i'm facing 
i figured that there is this statement using `IF()` and `CONCAT()` Functions 
combined to one different column . What i want to do is merge 
two values into one and make the first value look like a column .
This is my sql code so far :

```
SELECT 
    IF(meta_key = 'property_id',
        CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),
        '') AS property_id
FROM
    wp_postmeta,
    wp_posts,
    wp_terms,
    wp_term_taxonomy,
    wp_term_relationships
WHERE
    wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
        AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
        AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
```

It turns out to be empty but the rows are counted right .

Comment: if you obtain empty result could be that meta_key = 'property_id' return false and you get always  ''  try iusing  'empty' for check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Just move the condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value) AS property_id
FROM wp_postmeta pm JOIN
     wp_posts p
     ON pm.post_id = p.ID JOIN
     wp_term_relationships r
     ON r.object_id = p.ID JOIN
     wp_term_taxonomy tt
     ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id JOIN
     wp_terms t
     ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE meta_key = 'property_id'
```

Or, remove the `WHERE` and use `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN meta_key = 'property_id'
             THEN CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value)
             ELSE ''  -- Why not `NULL`?
        END) as property_id
```

I also note that most of the tables are not necessary for the operation you are doing.

Thanks (Luarb , sorry for bad edit)

Comment: Thank man it works like a charm, i edited it because it wp.post_id not pm.post_id , never mind just thanks alot :D

Comment: Another question regarding this subject , can i store this results into a column and than use another meta_key value to do the same thing into another  column ? example : meta_key = porperty_id is gonna be a column and meta_key = property_price another one column and etc..

Comment: @LuarbBalla . . . I think you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.